# using ASP.NET MVC and EXT JS together

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs

I'd like to use for my next project Ext js and ASP.NET MVC.

I'm wondering what would be the best way of using this two framework together. So far I did some project using ASP.NET MVC, where every action method returned a view and reloaded the page. The Ext js mvc application uses a single page approach.

As I'm pretty new to ext js so I'm wondering if someone could share some experiences of building real world application using this two frameworks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use extjs as you think is better for you. You can use its components as simple widgets or create a full javascript (extjs) client. However, which are the real requirements? a single page client or a traditional client?

In our current project we started using ASP.Net MVC Framework with extjs widgets, it was ok for a while but the customer wanted more and more sophisticated UI and a better user experince (among other thing) then, we changed the app, we left MVC models and controllers (views were removed) and we created a full javascript client with extjs 4.1.

After that we realized we were using an ASP M_C framework (with no views) and that was a nonsense so, we took the ASP MVC project away and replaced it by a WCF Rest service (it also could be done with an ASP.Net Web Api).

We feel proud of our decision and the resulting design. If you can, if you know extjs (learning it is rather hard) and javascript and, if you have support to your decision then, keep your application splitted in two:

a server-side service/api and,
a full javascript application.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you using Ext Direct ?

Comment: No, I am not using Direct.

Comment: At first I choose WCF because of missing View but then I turn back to MVC because of model validation/DataAnnotation supported by default. I also require at least 2 views (`/` and `/login`) to support server authentication (I also don't want to have another index.html inside login folder) and some other view that require request from server or security concern.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I'd agree with the answer by @lontivero, I'm currently working on a project using ASP.NET MVC as the backend and ExtJS as the front.

You do, as pointed out, loose the V from the ASP.NET MVC stack and you end up needing to duplicate you C# view models in you ExtJS Models on the client side but I've found using MVC as a backend (effectively as a rest based collection of Json end points) absolutely fine.

You can utilise the model binding, model validation in MVC whilst leveraging the full client side js app in Ext.

I'm curious as to the points you didn't get on with using this structure (I'm not saying it's perfect, but it does seem to work)

Comment: So you have for your create,index and update action methods separate views and you render the ext js components on each view from scratch ?

Comment: No, we end up with pretty much a single view and an entire ExtJS application, but we still use the action methods as urls for model/store proxies, view models to strongly type and validate the data coming in and out of the controller actions and authorisation annotations for security to different areas of the system for example.

Comment: +1 for validation. I would have 2 view. 1st for default/main and 2nd for `/login` view which will render a centered login dialog. I just thinking to use T4 in C# view models to generate Extjs models but not sure if it worth to do it.

Comment: Yeah we contemplated that side of things, it will depend on scale I think, we only have 10-15 models and it wasn't a major task to keep them in sync, but if you have hundreds and the project is long running it may be a pain to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

We used [Ext.NET](http://www.ext.net) (versions 0.x-1.x) in our previous projects. Even after a comprehensive effort to upgrade our projects to the (now current) version, we had to drop Ext.Net 2.x out.
If it fits you, it can help.

The main problems with Ext.Net were (several) incompatibilities with ASP.NET and a lack of trust. They used to keep their schedule, it's far from it for last 2 years or so. And they are behind ExtJS.